# Sum a group of lines, count for a group of lines

Tags: google-docs

Using google docs, I want to make it possible to have a sum for a the group of lines with A, B and C. And also to count how many W and L those groups have.

```
+-------+-------+--------+
| Group | Value | Result |
+-------+-------+--------+
| A     |     2 | W      |
| B     |     1 | W      |
| C     |     2 | W      |
| A     |     1 | L      |
| B     |     2 | L      |
| C     |     1 | L      |
| A     |     1 | L      |
| A     |     1 | L      |
+-------+-------+--------+
```

Having this table, as an example, the result should be:

Value of A=5

Value of B=3

Value of C=3

Result of A =
1W and 2L

Result of B= 1 Win and 1 L

Result of C = 1 W and 2 L

How can I do that using google docs?

Comment: and sumif to do the values

Answer (score 0):

Docs (the word processor) does not (yet?) have the features Word has for table formulae. However there is a free [add-on](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/gtable-calculator/fknnekoeejdjcbdokeinngldblilkedp?hl=en) that might be of interest.

One solution would be to copy your table into A1 (say) of a new Google Sheets (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>) and in E3:

```
=SUMIF(A:A,A3,B:B)
```

in F3:

```
=countifs($A:$A,$A3,$C:$C,"L")
```

copied across to G3.

In G3 change `L` to `W` and then copy E3:G3 down three rows.

This uses cell references for the `Group` in E3 but one could populate D3 with:

```
=sort(unique(A3:A))
```

and, before copying down, changing `A3` in E3 to `D3`.

If by docs you meant Sheets, then as above but no need to copy and paste the table out of Docs.